Elegant angle ordering test for rational arithmetic
I have three vectors in the plane, $a$, $b$ and $c$, notionally extending from the origin. I would like to determine whether, when sweeping a vector counterclockwise in the plane from $a$ to $c$, one encounters a vector which is in the same direction as $b$; equivalently, whether $a$ , $b$ and $c$ are ordered counterclockwise around the origin.
The simple approach, of course, is testing the sign of the determinant of $\begin{vmatrix}\hat{a}_x & \hat{a}_y & 1 \\ \hat{b}_x & \hat{b}_y & 1 \\ \hat{c}_x & \hat{c}_y & 1\end{vmatrix}$ (where $\hat{a} = a/|a|$), or equivalently the sign of $(\hat{b}-\hat{a}) \perp (\hat{c}-\hat{a})$ (where $\perp$ is the perp dot product). Note the normalization of the vectors, which is necessary for, say, $a=\langle2,2\rangle,\ b=\langle0,1\rangle,\ c=\langle-2,2\rangle$. Another approach involves computing counterclockwise angles, and testing whether $\angle aOb + \angle bOc = \angle aOc$. And a third family of approaches involves splitting up cases where, say, $a \perp c$ is positive or negative, and using different tests predicated on that one.
In my case, I'm working with exact rational arithmetic, so I can't evaluate square roots or transcendental functions. What test can I use to evaluate whether the vector angles are ordered CCW, without performing a normalization step or doing any trig? Ideally this would not involve exhaustive case analyses and conditionals (my current approach) either. Intuitively, I feel there must be something elegant out there... am I wrong?

maybe normalize only the x coordinates to be the same (a rational division) and then compare the y's

@user619894 That comes under the umbrella of "exhaustive case analysis", given that the signs of the $x$'s can differ.

I think breaking into two stages would be best:


If a,b,c are not all in the same quadrant, then the problem simplifies.  If a,b,c are all in different quadrants, it is trivial,  If b is in the same quadrant as a or c, you just have to do one "cross multiplication test" to see if b is on the correct size of the vector in its quadrant


if all 3 vectors are in the same quadrant, you will have to do 2 "cross multiplication tests"


If two vectors are both in the first quadrant, then a is ccw of b iff ay/ax >= by/bx <-> ay*bx >= ax*by
Otherwise, rotate them into the first quadrant

@hacatu That, too, comes under the umbrella of "exhaustive case analysis".

That's basically how I implemented this kind of test when I implemented a spherical kd tree with integer coordinates, unfortunately I don't know a better way, but it would be very interesting if you find one

I have not rigorously proven it yet, but I think if $2$ or $3$ out of $a_xb_y-a_yb_x,$ $b_xc_y-b_yc_x$ and $c_xa_y-c_ya_x,$ are positive, then the vectors are ordered counterclockwise, if $2$ or $3$ are negative, they are ordered clockwise.

Trying to "approximately normalize" the vectors (make their norms not 1 but close enough for the determinant or similar approaches to be useful) is probably not reasonably possible, so I think any simple approach would have to be of a different kind

@ReinhardMeier That does sound promising.

@ReinhardMeier I'm fairly sure your approach works. I'd suggest you put it in an answer too. You can include a warning that you haven't proved it yet if you aren't sure.

How does your “perp dot product” formula handle following the degenerate cases? (1) $a=c=0$, (2) $a=0\ne c$, (3) $a\ne0=c$, (4) $a=pc\ne0$ for some positive $p$.

@user1551 A zero vector makes no angle with the origin, so it’s not really in the domain.

$a$ and $c$ are nonzero in case (4), but the perp dot product is always zero regardless of the exact value of $b$.

@user1551 That’s a degenerate case, the boundary between angle orderings, so the sign of the determinant is (correctly) zero.

That’s my point: as the sign is zero, you cannot use the perp dot product formula to determine whether $a,b,c$ are arranged in anticlockwise order.

@user1551 of course you can. When there is no angle ordering (either cw or ccw), it tells you so.

No. For an ordering to be well defined, the angle between any vector and $a$ must be a number inside an half-closed, half-open interval of length $2\pi$, such as $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$. So, if $c$ is a positive multiple of $a$, the angle between them is zero. Hence $a,b,c$ is arranged in anticlockwise order if and only if $b$ is also a positive multiple of $a$.

@user1551 Thanks for your thoughts.

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
D_a & = & b_xc_y-b_yc_x \\
D_b & = & c_xa_y-c_ya_x \\
D_c & = & a_xb_y-a_yb_x
\end{eqnarray}
In the following, I assume that none of the vectors is the zero-vector.
It is easy to see that
\begin{eqnarray}
a_xD_a+b_xD_b+c_xD_c & = & 0 \\
a_yD_a+b_yD_b+c_yD_c & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(c_xD_c\right)^2 & = & \left(a_xD_a+b_xD_b\right)^2 \\
\left(c_yD_c\right)^2 & = & \left(a_yD_a+b_yD_b\right)^2
\end{eqnarray}
and
$$
\left(c_x^2+c_y^2\right)D_c^2
=
 \left(a_x^2+a_y^2\right)D_a^2
+2\left(a_xb_x+a_yb_y\right)D_aD_b
+\left(b_x^2+b_y^2\right)D_b^2
$$
or
$$
\|c\|^2D_c^2
=
 \|a\|^2D_a^2
+2\left\langle a,b\right\rangle\,D_aD_b
+\|b\|^2D_b^2
$$
With the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$
\|c\|^2D_c^2
\leq
 \|a\|^2D_a^2
+2\,\|a\|\,\|b\|\,|D_a|\,|D_b|
+\|b\|^2D_b^2
=
\left( \|a\|\,|D_a|+\|b\|\,|D_b| \right)^2
$$
which means
$$
\|c\|\,|D_c| \leq \|a\|\,|D_a|+\|b\|\,|D_b|
$$
Analogously
$$
\|a\|\,|D_a| \leq \|b\|\,|D_b|+\|c\|\,|D_c| \\
\|b\|\,|D_b| \leq \|c\|\,|D_c|+\|a\|\,|D_a|
$$
Consequently, the expression
$$
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c
$$
is positive if and only if at least two of the numbers $\|a\|D_a,$ $\|b\|D_b$ and $\|c\|D_c$ are positive, which means at least two of the numbers $D_a,$ $D_b$ and $D_c$ are positive (see "Edit" below)
We also have
$$
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c
=\begin{vmatrix}
a_x & a_y & \|a\| \\
b_x & b_y & \|b\| \\
c_x & c_y & \|c\|
\end{vmatrix}
=\|a\|\,\|b\|\,\|c\|\,
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat a_x & \hat a_y & 1 \\
\hat b_x & \hat b_y & 1 \\
\hat c_x & \hat c_y & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
which means that the statement "At least two of the numbers $D_a,$ $D_b$ and $D_c$ are positive" is equivalent with the statement
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat a_x & \hat a_y & 1 \\
\hat b_x & \hat b_y & 1 \\
\hat c_x & \hat c_y & 1
\end{vmatrix} > 0
$$
This leads to the following cases:
Case 1. All $3$ numbers out of $D_a,$ $D_b$ and $D_c$ are $0.$ All $3$ vectors are collinear. There is no way of making a statement about clockwise/counterclockwise orientation.
Case 2. Exactly $2$ numbers out of $D_a,$ $D_b$ and $D_c$ are $0.$ This is impossible. We could not simultaneously fulfill
$$
\|c\|\,|D_c| \leq \|a\|\,|D_a|+\|b\|\,|D_b| \\
\|a\|\,|D_a| \leq \|b\|\,|D_b|+\|c\|\,|D_c| \\
\|b\|\,|D_b| \leq \|c\|\,|D_c|+\|a\|\,|D_a|
$$
Case 3. One number is $0,$ one number is positive and one number is negative. Two vectors are pointing into the same direction, the third is pointing into an independent (neither the same nor the opposite) direction. There is no way of making a statement about clockwise/counterclockwise orientation.
Case 4. One number is $0,$ the other two have the same sign. Two vectors are pointing into opposite directions, the third is pointing into an independent (neither the same nor the opposite) direction. The sign of the non-zero numbers determines the orientation.
Case 5. All $3$ numbers are non-zero. The majority of the signs determines the orientation.
This allows us to interpret the result of
$$
\mathrm{sgn}\left(D_a\right)+
\mathrm{sgn}\left(D_b\right)+
\mathrm{sgn}\left(D_c\right)
$$
-3: clockwise, tips of normalized vectors form an acute triangle
-2: clockwise, tips of normalized vectors form a right triangle
-1: clockwise, tips of normalized vectors form an obtuse triangle
0: degenerate
1: counterclockwise, tips of normalized vectors form an obtuse triangle
2: counterclockwise, tips of normalized vectors form a right triangle
3: counterclockwise, tips of normalized vectors form an acute triangle
Edit
There is a subtle inaccuracy in the proof above. The statement
"The expression $\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c$ is positive if and only if at least two of the numbers $\|a\|D_a,$ $\|b\|D_b$ and $\|c\|D_c$ are positive"
does not follow from
$$
\|c\|\,|D_c| \leq \|a\|\,|D_a|+\|b\|\,|D_b| \\
\|a\|\,|D_a| \leq \|b\|\,|D_b|+\|c\|\,|D_c| \\
\|b\|\,|D_b| \leq \|c\|\,|D_c|+\|a\|\,|D_a|
$$
alone.
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix}
   \;\;(\|b\|\,D_b > 0\land \|c\|\,D_c > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|c\|\,D_c > 0\land \|a\|\,D_a > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|a\|\,D_a > 0\land \|b\|\,D_b > 0)
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\Longrightarrow
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c \geq 0
$$
and
$$
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c > 0
\Longrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
   \;\;(\|b\|\,D_b > 0\land \|c\|\,D_c > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|c\|\,D_c > 0\land \|a\|\,D_a > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|a\|\,D_a > 0\land \|b\|\,D_b > 0)
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
are trivial under that assumption, but
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix}
   \;\;(\|b\|\,D_b > 0\land \|c\|\,D_c > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|c\|\,D_c > 0\land \|a\|\,D_a > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|a\|\,D_a > 0\land \|b\|\,D_b > 0)
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\Longrightarrow
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c \neq 0
$$
needs some extra work and extra assumptions.
Note that
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat a_x & \hat a_y & 1 \\
\hat b_x & \hat b_y & 1 \\
\hat c_x & \hat c_y & 1
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
can happen only if the tips of the three vectors $\hat a,$ $\hat b$ and $\hat c$ form a degenerate triangle. You cannot create a degenerate triangle from points on a circle unless those points are all on the same line through the center of the circle or two points are identical. However, if all three vectors are collinear, we also have $D_a=D_b=D_c=0.$ If two points are identical and the three points are not lying on the same line through the center of the circle, then one number out of $D_a,$ $D_b$ and $D_c$ is negative, one is zero and one is positive. Conversely, this implies
$$
\left.
\begin{matrix}
   \;\;(\|b\|\,D_b > 0\land \|c\|\,D_c > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|c\|\,D_c > 0\land \|a\|\,D_a > 0) \\
\lor \;(\|a\|\,D_a > 0\land \|b\|\,D_b > 0)
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\Longrightarrow
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat a_x & \hat a_y & 1 \\
\hat b_x & \hat b_y & 1 \\
\hat c_x & \hat c_y & 1
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
\\
\Longrightarrow
\|a\|\,\|b\|\,\|c\|\,
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat a_x & \hat a_y & 1 \\
\hat b_x & \hat b_y & 1 \\
\hat c_x & \hat c_y & 1
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
\Longrightarrow
\|a\|\,D_a + \|b\|\,D_b + \|c\|\,D_c \neq 0
$$
which completes the proof.

I think those numbers are also $0$ when the vectors point in exactly opposite directions. But in such a case the question of orientation still makes sense. So, if these corner cases also have to be handled correctly they have to be checked separately.

If e.g. $D_b=0$ because $a$ and $c$ point in the opposite directions, then $D_a$ and $D_c$ necessarily have opposite signs if they're nonzero and it's enough to check one of them.

$D_b=0$ could also occur if $a$ and $c$ point into the same direction, in which case the clockwise/counterclockwise question does not make sense.

So we need to evalualue $D_a$ and $D_c$. If they have the same sign, then this sign determines the orientation. If they have opposite signs, we cannot determine the orientation.

I guess that in general if one the $D$s is $0$, then you have to check that the other two have opposite signs and that the sing is correct.

If two or all three are $0$, then either at least one of the vectors is a zero vector and/or at least two point in exactly the same direction. In those cases the orientation is meaningless.

@QuantumWiz "Exactly two" cannot happen. See my edited answer.

Exactly two can happen if one of the vectors is the zero vector.

@QuantumWiz You are right. I missed that. I have added an explicit exclusion of the zero-vector.

I am truly impressed by this approach, and by the illumination of its interpretation.

@Sneftel  Thank you for your kind words. Note that I have edited the answer to get rid of an inaccurracy regarding the inequalities.


Ideally this would not involve exhaustive case analyses and conditionals

I doubt that this is possible. Even in the real case, when $a=c$, your perp dot product is always zero. Hence this case has to be handled separately.
Moreover, an “exhaustive case analysis” may not be as complicated as it sounds. Assume that $a,b,c\ne0$. Denote by $R_\theta$ the matrix for an anticlockwise rotation by an angle $\theta$. Let $P=\pmatrix{a&c},\,J=\operatorname{adj}(P)$ and $\delta=\det P$. There are only four possible cases:

$\delta>0$. In this case, $\hat{c}=R_\theta\,\hat{a}$ for some $\theta\in(0,\pi)$. Therefore $a,b,c$ are arranged in anticlockwise order if and only if $b$ lies inside the closed nonnegative cone generated by $a$ and $c$, i.e., if and only if $P^{-1}b$ is a nonnegative vector (or equivalently, $Jb$ is a nonnegative vector).
$\delta<0$. In this case, $\hat{c}=R_\theta\,\hat{a} $ for some $\theta\in(-\pi,0)$. Therefore $a,b,c$ are arranged in anticlockwise order if and only if $b$ lies outside the open positive cone generated by $a$ and $c$, i.e., if and only if $P^{-1}b$ is not a positive vector (or equivalently, $Jb$ is not a negative vector).
$c$ is a positive multiple of $a$. Then $a,b,c$ are arranged in anticlockwise order if and only if $b$ is also a positive multiple of $a$.
$c$ is a negative multiple of $a$. Then $a,b,c$ are arranged in anticlockwise order if and only if $\langle b,R_{\pi/2}a\rangle\ge0$.

